# How can I list upgradeable Cabal packages in the style of `apt-show-versions`?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I was wondering if there was a way (either existing command or shell script or alike) to list registered GHC packages for which hackage has an updated version available. Something in the style of `apt-show-versions`, e.g.:

```
attoparsec upgradeable from 0.9.0.0 to 0.9.1.1
base uptodate at 4.3.1.0
...
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `cab` and then do

```
% cab sync
% cab outdated
```

http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/cab/en/

Comment: almost: If I've got multiple versions installed, I can't easily differentiate between those for which I have the latest version as well, and those for which I have only old versions

Comment: @hvr Perhaps you could send in a patch to the cab maintainer?

Comment: @DuBuisson, I've already filed an [issue report](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/cab/issues/1) to get into contact with the author